# TFS Check In event listener

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I want to listen a check in event when it occurs.Currently I am using TFS as version control.I am trying to listen tfs events using visual studio addin.But I want to listen the check in event, when we select the project and right click and select check in in context menu

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to monitor the TFS event (Server Side)?  or the Checkin event of Visual Studio when you click the button?

Comment: I want to listen the Visual studio Checkin event at client side

Comment: What do you want to achieve when listening to the check in event?

Comment: I want to save the project PMS details before a check in operation.I have successfully written the code for listen commit checkin event.But cannot  listen the solution explorer context menu checkin event.We have proposed to get the PMS details from user before checkin event and these details saved only if triggering of commitcheckin event